# How can I read from a file a specific string based on user input

Tags: python, file, search, input

I have a text file that lists disk drive details. I want to be able to input a string (e.g. 0:1:7) and have all the lines below that (up to 25 lines) printed to the screen (or to another file).

The problem is that there are 2 lines in the file that contain 0:1:7 (one line contains 0:1:7 only, the one I want, and the other line contains "Physical Disk 0:1:7") so it's printing everything twice. How can I ONLY print based on the first? Ignoring "Physical Disk 0:1:7"?

```
with open("driveDetails.txt", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
    slot = raw_input("What is the slot position? (e.g. 0:1:0) ")
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if slot in line:
        for l in searchlines[i:i+25]: print l,
        print
```

This prints out the line containing 0:1:7 +25 lines
AND 
it's also printing it again based on the line containing "Physical Disk 0:1:7" +25 lines.

```
ID                              : 0:1:7
Status                          : Ok
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:7
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Spun Up
...

Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:7
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Spun Up
...
```

I only want the first set printed. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: IUCC you should `break` the loop

Comment: facepalm... Thanks mad_!!